# I make project for temperature controller with pid and tmp36 , will my design work?

Tags: pid-controller

[image: Tinkercad Design]
[image: Schematic]

I design a close loop system with pid controller and feedback with tmp36 sensor

Comment: The bottom two op-amps are  railed and the I/D time constants are many orders of magnitude too low for a typical thermal system.

Comment: ok , but is the feedback sensor circuit connected to the error amp (differential opamp) correct? Will it work ?

Comment: The topology generally looks okay. You have not dealt with the TMP36 offset voltage.

Comment: Unless you have design specs and a plant equation for mass and max dT/dt of the control system and transformation of thermal resistance and asymmetric power level of heat/cooling, thus is inherently unstable when Op Amps go into saturation.